# How can I determine if two directories (including all subdirectories) are identical?

Tags: windows, filesystems, comparison

I have a directory containing many files spread across several subdirectories. I have a second copy of this directory in a different location, and I'd like to determine whether or not the contents of these directories are identical (and if not, where the discrepancies lie).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Define identical. Same name. Same bytes. Same timestamp. Etc.

Comment: Name, path (relative to the root directory), and bytes ought to do it I think.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of tools out there to do so

First one which comes to my mind was [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/download.htm) and the *Synchronize dirs* command. Here is a self explanatory image

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thanks! Do you know any other tools off the top of your head and why I should go with one over the other?

Comment: Directory Toolkit (https://www.funduc.com/directory_toolkit.htm) can give you a visual representation of which files are different (your choice of date&time or actual bytes) and can synch them if you wish.  Why go with one over the other?  That'd be up to you and your taste in software, no?

Comment: @nixda Total Commander worked great, thanks again for the recommendation.